# Problemas para insertar una fila en una tabla MySQL recién creada

Tags: mysql, insert

Estoy trabajando en una app para smartphones que consiste en una guía mineral. A la hora de crear el servicio REST del que la app obtiene la data, estoy teniendo problemas para insertar mis datos en tablas de DB MySQL.

He creado la siguiente tabla con 30 campos:

```
CREATE TABLE MINERALESEN(
ID TEXT,
NAME1 TEXT,
NAME2 TEXT,
TYPE TEXT,
CLASS TEXT,
GROUPE TEXT,
FORMULA TEXT,
SYSTEM TEXT,
ENV1 TEXT,
ENV1T TEXT,
ENV2 TEXT,
ENV2T TEXT,
ENV3 TEXT,
ENV3T TEXT,
ENV4 TEXT,
ENV4T TEXT,
ENV5 TEXT,
ENV5T TEXT,
HABIT TEXT,
COLOR TEXT,
DIAPHANEITY TEXT,
LUSTER TEXT,
STREAK TEXT,
WEIGHT TEXT,
WEIGHTAVG TEXT,
HARDNESS TEXT,
HARDNESSAVG TEXT,
CLEAVAGE TEXT,
FRACTURE TEXT,
LINK TEXT);
```

Intento insertar una fila con 30 valores.

```
INSERT INTO MINERALESEN VALUES(
'1',
'gold',
'oro',
'Non silicates.',
'Native elements.',
'Native elements.',
'Au',
'Cubic.',
'Hydrothermal',
'Associated with quartz veins.',
'Sedimentary',
'Placers.',
'Magmatic',
'IOCG deposits.',
'no',
'no',
'no',
'no',
'Octahedral crystals. Arborescent, scaly, nuggets.',
'Characteristic yellow.', 
'Opaque.',
'Metallic.',
'Characteristic yellow.',
'19.3',
'19.3',
'2.5-3',
'2.75',
'---',
'Splintery, indented.',
'(1)The Arkenstone. iRocks.com','http://www.irocks.com/minerals/specimen/46020'
);
```

Lo he contado una y mil veces y tanto la tabla como el insert tienen 30 valores, pero da el siguiente error:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE MINERALESEN(IDENTIFIER TEXT,NAME1 TEXT,NAME2 TEXT,TYPE TEXT,CLASS TEXT,GROUPE TEXT,FORMULA TEXT,SYSTEM TEXT,ENV1 TEXT,ENV1T TEXT,ENV2 TEXT,ENV2T TEXT,ENV3 TEXT,ENV3T TEXT,ENV4 TEXT,ENV4T TEXT,ENV5 TEXT,ENV5T TEXT,HABIT TEXT,COLOR TEXT,DIAPHANEITY TEXT,LUSTER TEXT,STREAK TEXT,WEIGHT TEXT,WEIGHTAVG TEXT,HARDNESS TEXT,HARDNESSAVG TEXT,CLEAVAGE TEXT,FRACTURE TEXT,LINK TEXT);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO MINERALESEN VALUES('1','gold','oro','Non silicates.','Native elements.','Native elements.','Au','Cubic.','Hydrothermal','Associated with quartz veins.','Sedimentary','Placers.','Magmatic','IOCG deposits.','no','no','no','no','Octahedral crystals. Arborescent, scaly, nuggets.','Characteristic yellow.','Opaque.','Metallic.','Characteristic yellow.','19.3','19.3','2.5-3','2.75','---','Splintery, indented.','(1)The Arkenstone. iRocks.com','http://www.irocks.com/minerals/specimen/46020');
ERROR 1136 (21S01): Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
mysql>
```

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: Pues parece que has contado mal :) En la última línea del `INSERT` tienes 2 elementos, si quitas uno de ellos deja de dar el error

Comment: @David JP Muchas gracias. Qué despistado. Si quieres añade una respuesta corta y la acepto rápido.

Comment: Bien visto @DavidJP, yo casi estaba pensando que era porque tiene una columna que se llama `TYPE`, la cual es una [palabra reservada de MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html). Dado que las columnas no se mencionan de forma explícita, entonces la consulta pasa. De todos modos, no conviene usar palabras reservadas para nombrar tablas o columnas.

Comment: @A.Cedano fue lo primero que comprobé haciendo uso de los ````, lo siguiente fue probar a quitar uno de los `VALUES` que estaban en la misma línea. @Universal_learner no te preocupes por los puntos, ya habrá más oportunidades con buenas respuestas... Despistes así los tenemos todos, y de estar un buen rato mirando sin verlo. No está de más que se vea que, planteando correctamente una pregunta (aportando el dataset y el código del intento), rápidamente se da con la solución